# Stripe connect refunds api ERROR "no such payment_intent"

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate use asynchronous response for a Webhook stripe with checkout.session.completed event. I'm working with firebase and flutterlfow to build a payment system. So what I do is basically manage any errors in the creation of the purchased services and, if necessary, manage the refund. Aside from the code I post, I notice that the refound API on postman is also not working properly. I don't understand where the mistake is/where I'm wrong. I ask you for help in understanding how to resolve it. Thank you all.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
// To avoid deployment errors, do not call admin.initializeApp() in your code 

//const functions = require('firebase-functions');
//const admin = require("firebase-admin");
//admin.initializeApp();
//const stripeTk = functions.config().stripe.token;

const axios = require('axios');
const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().stripe.token);
const stripeAccount = 'acct_1OT33cQlnlPZnFaP';

exports.stripeWebhook = functions
  .runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 60,
    memory: '256MB'
  })
  .https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    let clientReferenceId, amountTotal, paymentIntent, serviceRef, assoRef, stableRef, session;
    let userDoc, servicesRef, assoRefDoc;
    try {
      const event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
        req.rawBody,
        req.headers["stripe-signature"],
        functions.config().stripe.payments_webhook_secret
      );

      if (event.type === 'checkout.session.completed') {

        const db = admin.firestore();

        await db.runTransaction(async (transaction) => {
        const session = event.data.object;

        clientReferenceId = session.client_reference_id;
        amountTotal = session.amount_total;
        paymentIntent = session.payment_intent;
        serviceRef = session.metadata.serviceRef;
        assoRef = session.metadata.assoRef;
        stableRef = session.metadata.stableRef;

        userDoc = admin.firestore().collection("user").doc(clientReferenceId);
        servicesRef = admin.firestore().collection("stable").doc(stableRef)
                      .collection("Services").doc(serviceRef);
        assoRefDoc = assoRef ? admin.firestore().collection("user").doc(clientReferenceId).collection("Associated").doc(assoRef) : null;
        paymentDoc = db.collection("stable").doc(stableRef).collection("Payment").doc();

          const serviceSnapshot = await transaction.get(servicesRef);
          const serviceData = serviceSnapshot.data();

          if (serviceData.IsByAssociated && !assoRef) {
            throw new Error('AssocRefId is required for this service.');
          }

          throw new Error('ECCEZIONE DI TEST');
          return;
        
          transaction.set(paymentDoc, {
            Typo: 'Payment',
            AssociatedRef: assoRefDoc ?? '',
            ServicesRef: servicesRef ?? '',
            UserRef: userDoc ?? '',
            NeedAction: false,
            ManualAction: 'Nessuna',
            PricePaid: amountTotal / 100,
            Status: 'PAGAMENTO CONFERMATO',
            CreationDay: new Date(),
          });

          const currentDate = new Date();
          const expirationDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + (serviceData.DurationValidityDay * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

          transaction.set(userDoc.collection("BuyedServices").doc(), {
            IsActive: true,
            Description: serviceData.ShortDescription,
            Amount: serviceData.Amout || 0,
            PayedPrice: amountTotal / 100,
            Residual: serviceData.Amout || 0,
            IsLezione: serviceData.IsLesson,
            IsByAssociated: serviceData.IsByAssociated,
            AssociatedId: assoRefDoc ?? '',
            CreationDay: new Date(),
            ExpirationDay: expirationDate,
            PaymentIntent: paymentIntent
          });

        });

        res.sendStatus(200);
      } else {
        res.status(400).send('Unhandled event type');
      }
    } catch (err) {
        //session = event.data.object;
        clientReferenceId = session.client_reference_id;
        amountTotal = session.amount_total;
        paymentIntent = session.payment_intent;
        serviceRef = session.metadata.serviceRef;
        assoRef = session.metadata.assoRef;
        stableRef = session.metadata.stableRef;
      
    
      try {
        const refundResponse = await stripe.refunds.create({
  payment_intent: paymentIntent, // Assicurati che paymentIntent sia un ID valido
  // Altri dati rilevanti per il rimborso, se necessario
}, {
  stripeAccount: stripeAccount, // Passa l'account ID qui
});
        
        console.log(refundResponse.data);
        
        // Aggiorna il documento Firestore con le informazioni sul rimborso
        await admin.firestore().collection("stable").doc(stableRef)
          .collection("Payment").doc().set({
            Typo: 'Refund',
            AssociatedRef: assoRefDoc ?? '',
            ServicesRef: servicesRef ?? '',
            UserRef: userDoc ?? '',
            NeedAction: false,
            ManualAction: 'None',
            PricePaid: amountTotal / 100,
            Status: 'REFUND CONFIRMED'
          });

          console.error("Error processing webhook, Service Creation API call failed, refound done", err);
          res.status(500).send('Error processing webhook, Service Creation API call failed, refound done');
          
      } catch (refundError) {

        await admin.firestore().collection("stable").doc(stableRef)
        .collection("Payment").doc().set({
          Typo: 'RefundError',
          AssociatedRef: assoRefDoc ?? '',
          ServicesRef: servicesRef ?? '',
          UserRef: userDoc ?? '',
          NeedAction: true,
          ManualAction: 'Proceed with manual refund',
          PricePaid: amountTotal / 100,
          Status: 'ERROR DURING REFUND ATTEMPT'
        });
        // Se si verifica un errore durante il rimborso, gestisci la situazione di conseguenza
        // Potresti voler registrare il problema o prendere azioni manuali
        // Invia una risposta al webhook indicando l'errore
        console.error("Error processing refund:", refundError);
        res.status(500).send("Error processing refund. Need Human Action");
      }
    }
  });[Image of the error in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lkswu.png)
```

ps. I noticed that the api works when the purchase is handled by /v1/payment_intents. Also the tokens are correct, I don't see any errors. I also wrote to Stripe support, I'm waiting for their response.

Comment: That error means the PaymentIntent doesn't exist on the account you're making the API call on. Here you use the `stripeAccount` option so Stripe is looking for the PaymentIntent on that account, so if for example the PaymentIntent exists on a different account, or your platform account, you'd get that error. You need to carefully understand how your application uses Stripe Connect and charge models like Direct or Destination Charges and how the `stripeAccount` parameter ties in.

Comment: @karllekko I completely understand what you mean, basically if I have a connect system I can't use that API for the reound, but I have to use the method made available by stripe, correct?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean unfortunately. But if you're taking this existing Firebase extension which doesn't really have the concept of Connect, and are adding it in, then it's going to be complex since there are probably many Stripe API calls that the Firebase extension makes internally and many of them would have to be modified to support Connect concepts